# Set up custom library repo in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, software-distribution

I uploaded my lib to bintray to the custom private repo (myRepoName), then tried to use it in another project.

But I need to upload it somehow to dsl methods, otherwise it says `Gradle method not found myRepoName`

How to do it?

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    myRepoName { url "https://bintray.com/myRepo/sdk/repo" }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are using a custom name for the repository you are declaring. Instead you will have to call an existing method on `RepositoryHandler`, the underlying domain object for the `repositories` method. To fix the error message, you will have to use the method [maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#maven(groovy.lang.Closure)) for a Maven-based repository.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { 
            name 'myRepoName'
            url 'https://bintray.com/myRepo/sdk/repo' 
        }
    }
}
```

Please also keep in mind that there's a difference between the repositories you define within the `buildscript` block and for repositories defined on the top-level of the build script. Please refer to the Gradle user guide for more information.